# How to return Fetch response into a usable variable

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

This seems like a simple question but I've been stuck for some time and am hoping for some assistance. I'm POSTing data to a REST API, which if successful, returns a status message via a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{"variableone":123,"variabletwo":34}
```

I want to store that JSON result into an array and then use the variables. What am I doing wrong?

```
function showResults(response)
{
   var responsevar = response.variabletwo;
   console.log(responsevar);
}

function doPOST(postval,callback) {
    fetch("/api/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: $.param(postval)
    }).then(function (response) {
       if (callback) {
         callback(response);
       }
    });
}

doPOST({"checkclean":"11234"},showResults);
```

The code above does the POST properly and gets a result that I am expecting and can see in the Network->XHR-Preview in inspector, but I can't seem to get or user the actual variables from the result, ie. `variableone` and `variabletwo`.

Comment: None of this is jQuery, except for `$.param()`. jQuery provides `$.ajax()`, `fetch()` is native JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `response.json()` to parse the JSON.

```js
function showResults(response) {
  var responsevar = response.variabletwo;
  console.log(responsevar);
}

function doPOST(postval, callback) {
  fetch("/api/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: $.param(postval)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(response) {
      if (callback) {
        callback(response);
      }
    });
}

doPOST({
  "checkclean": "11234"
}, showResults);
```

Comment: What if you change `console.log(responsevar)` to `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Before adding the ```.then(response => response.json())``` code you suggested that would show me what I was looking for, but I couldn't use that json data...  after adding the response.json() code you suggested it comes back as undefined too

Comment: If you don't call `response.json()`, it shows you the JSON string, it's not parsed into an object.

Comment: Maybe there's something else before/after the JSON, which is causing the parse to fail. Make sure the response contains *only* JSON.

Comment: Use the Network tab to see the full response.

Comment: The response definitely contains only JSON.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the result being a Promise

Comment: No, that's what `.then()` is for. Look at the first example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch My answer is similar.

Comment: It's not a JSON issue. If I do alert(response.json()) it says [object Promise]

Comment: That's normal, it's why you need another `.then()` to process it.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested exactly but it doesn't work. I do appreciate that you tried to help tho. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.catch()` callback in case there's an error?